# ConcurrentHasMap how to Avoid conflict to modify the sizeCtl in the function of transfer

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

```
 if (i < 0 || i >= n || i + n >= nextn) {
            int sc;
            if (finishing) {
                nextTable = null;
                table = nextTab;
                sizeCtl = (n << 1) - (n >>> 1);
                return;
            }
            if (U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc = sizeCtl, sc - 1)) {
                if ((sc - 2) != resizeStamp(n) << RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT)
                    return;
                finishing = advance = true;
                i = n; // recheck before commit
            }
        }
```

How to ensure no conflict in ： sizeCtl = (n << 1) - (n >>> 1); and U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc = sizeCtl, sc - 1)；

for example ： 2 thread into this fucntion, and one thread has finished and set sizeCtl = (n << 1) - (n >>> 1);
another thread executed the U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc = sizeCtl, sc - 1) successed,so the sizeCtl = (n << 1) - (n >>> 1) -1? and not equal 0.75 * 2n。in otehr words,sizeCtl Not necessarily equal to 0.75 * n？